# ContentChildren returns a QueryList of undefined if read: TemplateRef

Tags: angular

I have a component and I need the list of my content children as `TemplateRef`.

If I read them with:

```
@ContentChildren(ToggleComponent) toggles: QueryList<ToggleComponent>;
```

Then it works, `toggles._results` is an array of objects of type `ToggleComponent`, and that's the expected behavior. I want the `TemplateRef` instead, so I tried:

```
@ContentChildren(ToggleComponent, {read: TemplateRef}) toggles: QueryList<ToggleComponent>;
```

But in this case `toggles._results` is an array of *undefined*s:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Why doesn't it work?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yveoeh) is a minimal reproduction of the error, you can see the `QueryList` object in the console.

Comment: To get TemplateRef you need to have Embedded template but you haven't

Comment: What's an embedded template?

Comment: `ng-template` or structural directive represents Embedded view

Comment: I don't understand, I don't find any reference about what you say. How can I make work my code? Adding `ng-template` doesn't work.

Comment: There is no TemplateRef on ToggleComponent. Wrap this component in ng-template and query it like `@ContentChildren(TemplateRef)`

Comment: Still not working. Now `toggles._results` is an empty array

Comment: Check console https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egpsrc?file=app/accordion.component.ts

Comment: Ok my mistake was wrapping the serie of ToggleComponent in `ng-template`, instead you wrapped each of them.

Anyways I don't like this solution, seriously do we need to change the public interface of the component in order to read the template ref of the ContentChildren? Other users already use my component and I don't want to introduce a breaking change, besides this it also looks ugly and useless, since a user could wonder why he needs to put "ng-template" everywhere.

Anyways I don't want to bother you anymore, I'm going to open an issue on Github. Thank you anyways

Comment: What is the purpose of having TemplateRef from component? TemplateRef is used for structural changes

Comment: I want to instantiate the view elsewhere using `ngTemplateOutlet`

Comment: Hey, you might be interested in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502461/ng-content-in-for-loop