# ng-content in for loop

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent

I'm trying to create a tab component using bootstrap.

```
<app-tabs>
  <app-tab [label]="'label1'">Description 1</app-tab>
  <app-tab [label]="'label2'">Description 2</app-tab>
</app-tabs>
```

I had a look at this article:
https://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/learning-ng2-creating-tab-component/
but my use case is different.

I need to use a different `<ng-content>` in each loop of the for.
This is my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/N2p8Vx?p=preview
It prints both descriptions in the second tab, leaving the first one empty.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can take a look at how angular material implemented tabs control.

There are some caveats about this approach https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18691 but anyway here is simplified version:

**tab.component.ts**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab',
  template: `
    <ng-template>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ng-template>`
})
export class TabComponent {
  ...

  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

**tabs.component.ts**

```typescript
<div *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index" 
           class="tab-pane" [ngClass]="{'active': i === 0}"...>
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tab.template"></ng-container>
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/NDgRCR?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you very much @yurzui. That's the solution I was looking for. I had tried the `*ngTemplateOutlet` but I didn't realize I needed to put the TemplateRef in the TabComponent. Cheers!

Comment: Plunker example is very nice! This is the power aka (complexity) that angular can achive